# SQL Server - Syntax error near "Primary" upon execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

When execute my SELECT statement I receive a syntax error near "Primary". What am I missing?

```
SELECT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM Production.ProductProductPhoto WHERE Primary = 1);
```

Comment: You are listing products that have a primary photo.  But they could have another one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how would I only primary photo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: You should write "Primary" between square brackes `[Primary]`. Because it is a reserved word.

**EDIT**

And, if you should narrow your results to the products that has only a primary photo, you have to add a second `where` condition:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE 
    ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM Production.ProductProductPhoto WHERE [Primary] = 1)
    AND ProductID NOT IN (SELECT ProductID FROM Production.ProductProductPhoto WHERE [Primary] = 0);
```

Comment: Flying in the face of all the upvotes, this is a comment, not an answer. Just sayin', not voting down. :)

Comment: @EricBrandt I saw the error and didn´t realize his "logical mistake". Thanks!

Comment: And then the moral obligation to go back and answer. Well played. +1!

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr This returns all the same rows as my original code.